# Change Div's Border During Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have a simple div.

```
<div id="sample"></div>
```

I made its border transparent using the code below:

```
var sample_div =  document.getElementById('sample');
sample_div.style.borderColor = 'transparent';
```

I want to make the div's border to blue when the mouse pointer is on hover. Below is my css code:

```
#sample:hover{ 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-color: blue;

}
```

My css code does not work.It does not change color when hovered by the mouse pointer. It stays transparent. Why?

Comment: `#sample_div:hover{` ==> `#sample:hover {`

Comment: inline style is given more preference use a `class` instead or use `!important`

Comment: @Tushar --> I type it incorrectly in my post. The problem is still not changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div#sample:hover{ 
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
}
```

//use **!important**

Answer (score 7):

You don't need JS & your IDs don't match.

```
#sample{
  background: #eee;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

#sample:hover{ 
    border-color: blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrqYZy

Answer (score 5):

Add `border:0` in `#sample` instead of doing the same using javascript.

```css
#sample {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 0;
}
#sample:hover{ 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your id's are not matching. Try as below:

```
#sample:hover{ 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS only.If you want to do it with JS , it will look like this.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

    var element = document.getElementById('sample');
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter',changeBorder);
});

function changeBorder(){
    document.getElementById('sample').style.border = '5px solid orange';
}
```

I am not that advanced with JS but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the `border-color` with JavaScript it becomes a inline style `<div id="sample" style="border-color: transparent;"></div>`.

The [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of an inline style is **higher** than the specificity of an :hover pseudo-class. So the `border-width` and `border-style` are set by the `:hover` but the `border-color` is still overwritten by the inline style (transparent) you set with your JavaScript.

To make it work either make the specificity of the rule higher with css by adding `!important` or ditch the JavaScript and set the initial styling by CSS so the specificity is not a problem anymore.